# How to use elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk

Tags: python, elasticsearch, helper, bulk

Can someone advice how to use function elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk instead elasticsearch.helpers.bulk for indexing data into elasticsearch.

If I simply change streaming_bulk instead of bulk, nothing gets indexed, so I guess it needs to be used in different form.

Code below creates index, type and index data from CSV file in chunks of 500 elemens into elasticsearch. It is working properly but I am wandering is it possible to increse prerformance. That's why I want to try out streaming_bulk function.

Currently I need 10 minutes to index 1 million rows for CSV document of 200MB. I use two machines, Centos 6.6 with 8 CPU-s, x86_64, CPU MHz: 2499.902, Mem: 15.574G total. 
Not sure can it go any faster.

```
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch([{'host': 'uxmachine-test', 'port': 9200}])
index_name = 'new_index'
type_name = 'new_type'
mapping = json.loads(open(config["index_mapping"]).read()) #read mapping from json file

es.indices.create(index_name)
es.indices.put_mapping(index=index_name, doc_type=type_name, body=mapping)

with open(file_to_index, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)        #read documents for indexing from CSV file, more than million rows
    content = {"_index": index_name, "_type": type_name}
    batch_chunks = []
    iterator = 0

    for row in reader:
        var = transform_row_for_indexing(row,fields, index_name, type_name,id_name,id_increment)
        id_increment = id_increment + 1
        #var = transform_row_for_indexing(row,fields, index_name, type_name)
        batch_chunks.append(var)
        if iterator % 500 == 0:
            helpers.bulk(es,batch_chunks)
            del batch_chunks[:]
            print "ispucalo batch"
        iterator = iterator + 1
    # indexing of last batch_chunk
    if len(batch_chunks) != 0:
        helpers.bulk(es,batch_chunks)
```

Answer (score 15):

So streaming bulk returns an interator.  Which means nothing will happen until you start iterating over it.  The code for the 'bulk' function looks like this:

```
success, failed = 0, 0

# list of errors to be collected is not stats_only
errors = []

for ok, item in streaming_bulk(client, actions, **kwargs):
    # go through request-reponse pairs and detect failures
    if not ok:
        if not stats_only:
            errors.append(item)
        failed += 1
    else:
        success += 1

return success, failed if stats_only else errors
```

So basically calling just streaming_bulk(client, actions, **kwargs) won't actually do anything.  It's not until you iterate over it as is done in this for loop that the indexing actually starts to happen.

So in your code.  You are welcome to change 'bulk' to 'streaming_bulk' however you need to iterate over the results of streaming bulk in order actually have anything indexed.

Answer (score 5):

`streaming_bulk` consumes an iterator of `actions` and yields a response for every action.
So you would first need to write a simple iterator over your documents like this:

```
def document_stream(file_to_index):
    with open(file_to_index, "rb") as csvfile:
        for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
            yield {"_index": index_name,
                   "_type": type_name,
                   "_source": transform_row(row)
                   }
```

And then to do the streaming bulk insert

```
stream = document_stream(file_to_index)
for ok, response in streaming_bulk(es, actions = stream):
    if not ok:
        # failure inserting
        print response
```