# How to retry indexing with elasticsearch-py when using bulk streaming?

Tags: elasticsearch-py

I have occasional `BulkIndexError` when using `streaming_bulk` helper. Is there any way to configure client to retry on such errors? What is the best way to handle errors when using helpers?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could set up your streaming pipeline in a way, so as to retry on errors (I believe, this will be a `BulkIndexError`).

The response from `streaming_bulk` is a tuple that looks like `ok, item` [see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659198/how-to-use-elasticsearch-helpers-streaming-bulk)]. Now, if you wrap the request to `streaming_bulk` in a try, and in your except, not empty out your list of actions, you could have this `try-except` block in an infinite loop, and break out when your list of actions is empty.

Comment: Do you have an example?