# Elasticsearch streaming_bulk generator not iterable

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to index some documents using the `elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk` function. When I try to get the results using the examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659198/how-to-use-elasticsearch-helpers-streaming-bulk), I get the error: `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`.

This is my function:

```
import elasticsearch.helpers
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

def index_with_streaming_bulk(self):

    all_body = []

    with open(self.geonames_file, encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:

        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
        body = []
        next(reader)  # skip column names
        for row_ind, row in enumerate(reader):
            body.append({
                "index": {
                    "_id": row_ind+1  # to map index value to geonames. remove the column headers
                }
            })
            doc = {}

            for field_tup in self.included_cols:
                field_name = field_tup[0]
                field_ind = field_tup[1]
                field_type = field_tup[2]
                val_init = row[field_ind]

                mod_val = self.transform_value(field_type, val_init)
                doc[field_name] = mod_val

            body.append(doc)
            all_body.append(body)

    def gendata():
        for body in all_body:
            yield body

    res = elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk(client=es, actions=gendata, chunk_size=500,
                                                             max_retries=5, initial_backoff=2, max_backoff=600,
                                               request_timeout=20)

    for ok, response in res:
        print(ok, response)
```

EDIT:
This is the full stack trace:

```
"C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\python.exe" C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/ElasticSearch/ES_Indexer_Geonames.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/ElasticSearch/ES_Indexer_Geonames.py", line 267, in <module>
    Indexer(init_hydro_concat, index_name, doc_name).index_with_streaming_bulk()
  File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/ElasticSearch/ES_Indexer_Geonames.py", line 207, in index_with_streaming_bulk
    for ok, response in res:
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\helpers\__init__.py", line 176, in streaming_bulk
    actions = map(expand_action_callback, actions)
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please paste full stack trace. Probably you used name of a function instead of it's result as one of parameters somewhere. But it's quite difficult to guess where without trace.

Comment: @running.t I put the whole stack trace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was due to the construction of the body dict. I needed to create the body as a dict, and include all body dicts into a list.
This is the solution:

```
def index_with_streaming_bulk(self):

    all_body = []

    with open(self.geonames_file, encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:

        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
        body = {}
        next(reader)  # skip column names

        for row_ind, row in enumerate(reader):

            body['_index'] = self.index_name
            body['_type'] = self.doc_type
            body['_id'] = row_ind + 1  # to map index value to geonames. remove the column headers

            for field_tup in self.included_cols:
                field_name = field_tup[0]
                field_ind = field_tup[1]
                field_type = field_tup[2]
                val_init = row[field_ind]

                mod_val = self.transform_value(field_type, val_init)
                body[field_name] = mod_val

            all_body.append(body)
            body={}

    def gendata():
        for body in all_body:
            yield body

    res = elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk(client=es, actions=all_body, chunk_size=1000, max_retries=5,
                                               initial_backoff=2, max_backoff=600, request_timeout=3600)
    for ok, response in res:
        print(ok, response)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [`elasticsearch.helpers.streamin_bulk`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk) documentation `actions` parameter is an iterable containing the actions to be executed, but not a function generating this iterable.

I found several [examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/104890/elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk) of usage of that function and in all cases value of `actions` parameter is a result of function not a function itself. So  I believe in your case it should be:

```
   res = elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk(client=es, actions=gendata(), chunk_size=500, max_retries=5, initial_backoff=2, max_backoff=600, request_timeout=20)
```

Note **()** after `gendata` which means this function is actually called and generator producing result is passed as an argument, not a function itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried that, but now I get this error: `TypeError: pop() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)`